# Visual Studio 2010 TFS Build Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfsbuild

I'm setting up VS 2010 Team Foundation Server for a personal project. It is overkill for a single developer but It is a learning experience for me. I'm having a problem with the build configuration. I set up a controller and agent with the default settings. However, when I run a build I get the following error:

> The project file 'C:\Builds...{Solution}.sln' was not found.

I find that the folder is created, but it is empty. Looking for a push in the right direction here. Thanks.

Comment: Can you get latest files from a different machine and check if they are compilable?

Comment: I only have one machine.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Build Definition and make sure that the Workspace tab is filled in correctly. something like `$/FolderWithMySolutionFile -> $(SourceDir)` and that it's set to Active, not Cloaked

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh190721.aspx